# Lines of records increased when data exported from hive into a csv on hadoop edge node

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, export-to-csv

I am facing an issue where Lines of records increase by 22,63,728 records when data exported from hive into a csv on hadoop edge node.

Sample command :
beeline -u $HIVE_JDBC_URL --silent=true --outputformat=tsv2 --showHeader=false --silent=true -e "use db; select * from table" > sample.csv

Any clue why this would happen ?

Comment: Also, my guess is something happens when it tries to decrypt few rows during taking the export. 
Sample : 

beeline -u $HIVE_JDBC_URL --silent=true --outputformat=tsv2 --showHeader=false --silent=true -e "use db; select DECRYPT(string(a.DECRYPTID), string(abc)) as abc , from db.table a" > sample.csv

Comment: some value or decrypted value contains newline characters.

Comment: @leftjoin Sure I will check if that is the case.